# Thinning ireegular temporal data for temporal independace of 1 hour

Tags: r, time, overlap, temporal

I am using the 'Overlap' package to observe predator-prey interactions of Feral cats vs all other animals.

I am using data obtained from camera traps left out for a few months. The camera's where set to take photo's every 30 seconds when there was movement in front of them.

I need to remove all instances where a particular animal (eg: Cats) occurs more than once within an hour period. If all the instances are counted we might be counting the same animal and accidentally inflating the data.

The problem I have is I don't know how to delete all that occur within the same hour with reference to the last sighting. I don't need to delete all duplicates within say 1 am or 2 am, but need to delete all duplicates within the same hour period in reference to the last one (eg: sighting at 1:50 am and 2:01 am would be the same animal).

Wondering if anyone has any idea's of how to achieve this. Should I use the 'Lubridate' package?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Hello @Phil I am not sure how to attach my data frame or excel  which is all I have to add as I have no idea which package to use to achieve this. 

Here is the vinegette of the 'Overlap' package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/overlap/vignettes/overlap.pdf

I am seeking how to thin my temporal records to exuding all that are not within one hour of each other. Records where not taken at set times.